# OpenLayers - "color-space/lchuv.js" not included in v8.2 download?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm just trying out some OpenLayers sample code (see below) with a download of version 8.2 but I get an error related to "color-space/lchuv.js" not found.

```
import Map from '/ol/Map.js';
import OSM from '/ol/source/OSM.js';
import TileLayer from '/ol/layer/Tile.js';
import View from '/ol/View.js';

const map = new Map({
   target: 'map',
   layers: [
     new TileLayer({
       source: new OSM(),
     }),
   ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
  }),
});
```

When I switched to a download of version 8.1 then the error disappears.

It seems to be a change to color.js.  v8.2 references 'color-space/lchuv.js' which doesn't seem to be included.  v8.1 references math.js.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a directory missing from v8.2?

Comment: What do you mean by "a download of version 8.2"? color-space is an external dependency. You might want to `npm install ol@8.2.0` instead of manually downloading the library. There are other external dependencies, and you're missing all of them when you don't use npm or a similar package manager to manage dependencies.

Comment: Ah.  So I was doing something wrong.  This page https://openlayers.org/download/ was giving three options for install and I was choosing the download option.  I assumed it had all the dependencies included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the downloaded version (https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/download/v8.2.0/v8.2.0-package.zip for v8.2.0) properly, i.e. with all dependencies except `geotiff` and `ol-mapbox-style` included, reference `dist/ol.js` from the downloaded zip in a script tag and `ol.css` in a style tag in your HTML page. Then in your JavaScript, don't use any imports. Instead, use `ol.Map`, `ol.View`, `ol.layer.Tile`, `ol.source.OSM` etc. directly.

```js
const map = new ol.Map({
   target: 'map',
   layers: [
     new ol.layer.Tile({
       source: new ol.source.OSM(),
     }),
   ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
  }),
});
```

```html
<script src="path/to/dist/ol.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/ol.css">
```

Comment: In this instance, how would you go about using the default controls for the map? I am in the process of trying to move from OL3 to the same version as OP, but I can't find a suitable replacement for `new ol.Map({controls: ol.control.defaults() ... })`.

Comment: That's `ol.control.defaults.defaults()` now.